# Why does using getaddrinfo with node as NULL and ai_flags as PASSIVE result in incorrect IP address?

Tags: c

why did the program print out my IP address as 0.0.0.0? If I specify my IP address, it would the correct IP.  I read through section about getaddrinfo in man page and see that assign AI_PASSIVE and NULL as in the code is valid. so, What is wrong here?

update: allocate memory for res and sa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "../cus_header/cus_header.h"

#define MYPORT "30000"
#define BACKLOG 10


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    res = malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo)); // update here
    char ip4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct sockaddr_in *sa;
    sa = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); // update here

    // load up address struct with getaddrinfo
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &res) == -1){
        error("Cannot get AI");
    }

    sa = (struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa->sin_addr), ip4, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("The IPv4 address is: %s\n", ip4);

    free(res); // update here
    free(sa); // update here

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Start by allocating memory for `res` and `sa`.

Comment: @m0skit0 I update the code as you said but the result did not change at all. As your suggestion, I guess getaddrinfo doesnot return a pointer to res, does it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual:

```sh
man 3 getaddrinfo
```

> If the AI_PASSIVE flag is specified in hints.ai_flags, and node is NULL, then the returned
>   socket addresses will be suitable for bind(2)ing a socket that will accept(2) connections.
>   The returned socket address will contain the "wildcard  address"  (INADDR_ANY  for  IPv4
>   addresses, IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT for IPv6 address). The wildcard address is used by applications
>   (typically servers) that intend to accept connections on any of the  hosts's  network
>   addresses. If node is not NULL, then the AI_PASSIVE flag is ignored.

So 0.0.0.0 is not an incorrect address, but the **wildcard  address**, that is, any of the addresses of the host.